# How To store data in Sql database in Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure

I face this problem when I store my data in Microsoft Azure Cloud.

here error log:

> Server Error in '/' Application. A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

**This is my code:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int userId = 0;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=asimo.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=asimo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=veeraiyan;Password=***********");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into registration(username,password,email)values('" + txtusername.Text + "','" + txtpassword.Text + "','" + txtemail.Text + "')", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text.Trim());
    userId = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    string message = string.Empty;
    switch (userId)
    {
        case -1:
            message = "Username already exists.\\nPlease choose a different username.";
            break;
        case -2:
            message = "Supplied email address has already been used.";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Registration successful.\\nUser Id: " + userId.ToString();
            break;
    }
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
}
```

Comment: Quick question, you use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` however you don't actually use parameters in your query you still have `values('" + txtusername.Text + "','" + txtpassword.Text + "','" + txtemail.Text + "')`. That really *REALLY* should be `)values(@username, @password, @email)` Also, you are storing passwords without hashing them, this is a extreemly bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connectionstring for an Azure Sql Server database should be written as

```
string cnString = @"Data Source=tcp:asimo.database.windows.net,1433;
                   Database=asimo;Trusted_Connection=False;
                   User ID=veeraiyan@asimo;Password=***********;
                   Encrypt=True;";
```

Said that, your code to insert a record and to retrieve the IDENTITY column UserID is not parameterized as it should be.

The correct approach is the following

```
string cmdText = @"insert into registration
                   (username,password,email)
                   values(@username, @password, @email);
                   SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con))
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text.Trim());
    userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    ...
```

Notice that to retrieve the UserID you don't get the return value of ExecuteNonQuery. This method returns only the number of rows inserted by your command. Instead you could put two commands together, the first one inserts the record, the second one returns the value of the last IDENTITY generated by your connection. The method used is ExecuteScalar that returns the first column of the first row (from the last SELECT statement).

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.google.com/search?q=agoogle&ie=&oe=#q=agoogle+c-sharp+azure+sql+connection+string for  your connection string issue. Then, as suggested in comments, change:

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into registration(username,password,email)values('" + txtusername.Text + "','" + txtpassword.Text + "','" + txtemail.Text + "')", con);

 //change your connection string to an Azure-compatible one...
```

to:

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into registration(username,password,email)values(@username,@password,@email, con);
```

and while you're at it, change:

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=asimo.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=asimo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=veeraiyan;Password=***********");
```

to:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=asimo.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=asimo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=veeraiyan;Password=***********")){

 //....

 }
```

Comment: you correct my code in SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into registration(username,password,email)values(@username,@password,@email, con); but you missed closing bracket where will be close i little bit confused..

Comment: No, but I provided you a link to learn how to do it yourself. See the link at the top of my answer - if you had searched for that in the first place, you wouldn't have needed to ask the question.

Comment: ou correct my code in SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into registration(username,password,email)values(@username,@passw‌​ord,@email, con); but you missed closing bracket where will be close i little bit confused

Comment: Am getting this kind of error please find me where i made mistake Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: You have a null value in your database and are attempting to cast that value into a c# type. Where are you getting the error, specifically? What is the code in the line that is producing the error?